# How to StreamWrite color of brushes in List<DrawAction>?

Tags: c#, winforms, list, class, stream

```
class DrawAction
{
    public Rectangle Dortgen { get; set; }
    public Brush Firca { get; set; }
    public PointF Koordinat { get; set; }
    public DrawAction(Brush color_, Rectangle rect_ )
    { Dortgen = rect_; Firca = color_; }
    public DrawAction(Brush color_)
    { Firca = color_; }
    public DrawAction (PointF k_)
    { Koordinat = k_; }
}
    List<DrawAction> kare = new List<DrawAction>();
    Brush brush = new SolidBrush(Color.Red);

    private void Panel1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (SeciliSekil == "Dikdortgen")
        {
            if (End.Y > Start.Y && End.X > Start.X)
                kare.Add(new DrawAction(brush, new Rectangle(Start.X, Start.Y, End.X - Start.X, End.Y - Start.Y)));
            else if (End.Y < Start.Y && End.X > Start.X)
                kare.Add(new DrawAction(brush, new Rectangle(Start.X, End.Y, End.X - Start.X, Start.Y - End.Y)));
            else if (End.Y > Start.Y && End.X < Start.X)
                kare.Add(new DrawAction(brush, new Rectangle(End.X, Start.Y, Start.X - End.X, End.Y - Start.Y)));
            else if (End.Y < Start.Y && End.X < Start.X)
                kare.Add(new DrawAction(brush, new Rectangle(End.X, End.Y, Start.X - End.X, Start.Y - End.Y)));
        }

    private void SaveButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        StreamWriter dortgenrenk = File.CreateText("DortgenRenk.txt");
        dortgenrenk.Close();

        StreamWriter DortColor;
        List<string> DortC = new List<string>();
        foreach (DrawAction yazdortC in kare)
            DortC.Add((yazdortC.Firca).ToString());
        foreach (string s in DortC)
        {
            DortColor = File.AppendText("DortgenRenk.txt");
            DortColor.WriteLine(s);
            DortColor.Close();
        }
    }
```

Here is some of my code. I keep brush data in List kare. I want to reach all the brushes and get their colors to write them into .txt. I tried this.

Now it saves something. I opened the .txt. There was writing " System.Drawing.SolidBrush ". But I need color.

Comment: I really wonder why you changed the Color to Brush; a Color can easily work with a SolidBrush and also a Pen. Anyway: You should store the only relevant property of SolidBrush : Color. As I already told you you need to cast a Brush to SolidBrush before you can access the Color. And, as I also told you, the simplest way is to then convert the Color to long `((SolidBrush)yourbrush).Color.ToArgb().ToString()` - Also: I suggest to name all elements of future applications in English.

Comment: DortC.Add((((SolidBrush)yazdortC.Firca).Color).ToArgb().ToString()); I wrote this code. Now for four different colors ,text is -16776961
-16744448
-8388480
-16777216

Comment: Does this mean something ?

Comment: Is this unexpected? Did you have four different colors? Can you reconstruct the original colors (via Color.FromArgb(long)) ? (( you could also use `((SolidBrush)yourbrush).Color.ToString()`. Much easier to read and understand. Much harder to process.. (note that the long is constructed from four bytes; long is signed and the minus simply means that the very first bit is set. So it really means nothing to worry about)

Comment: Your colors were blue, green, violet and black.

Comment: that's right. Thank you

Comment: -16776961 how can I convert this ? RectangleColor[b] ---> this holds the value and I 'm trying to draw rectangle with it. g.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(int.Parse(RectangleColor[b]))),.......) I tried this. First there was no mistake but when I run the program there is an error.

Comment: Looks right, although I would __never lump so many things__ is one line or call; this make it really hard to debug. Maybe to string doesn't really hold a number? What is the error?

Comment: System.Exception: '{X=194,Y=124,Width=51,Height=56}, not valid for Int32 .'

Comment: There is no problem with color.

Comment: RectangleConverter r = new RectangleConverter(); (Rectangle)r.ConvertFromString(Rectangle[b])
This is Rectangle coordinates code. Error is here.

Comment: g.FillEllipse((brush code is ok), (Rectangle)r.ConvertFromString(Rectangle[t]));  Here is an error says System.Exception: '{X=194,Y=124,Width=51,Height=56}, not valid for Int32 .

Comment: You really ought to learn how to look up basic functions. This is no way to abuse the SO comment system. If you do even a bsic test with RectangleConverter you will see what format the resulting string has, namely, e.g. `0; 0; 879; 524`  ; which obviously is what he expects when converting back.

Comment: Let's start again. First I draw a rectangle. At the same time I List the coordinates using List<DrawAction>. Then I save them to txt. It saves like this {X=194,Y=124,Width=51,Height=56}. But you say it should be like this 0; 0; 879; 524

Comment: Isn't there a way to use {X=194,Y=124,Width=51,Height=56}. Or I have to use Split make it 0; 0; 879; 524 like this ?

Comment: Instead you should create the string not from ToString but from the Rectangle.Converter

Comment: That makes sense. Thank you again

Comment: This time, I saved coordinates like you said and draw rectangles and saved it. Closed and ran the program again. Then load the .txt file and rectangles are drawn. I did same thing for ellipse but there was IsOutOfRange exception. I looked at the .txt and there was no problem.

Comment: if (file.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {                for (int b = 0; b < RectangleColor.Length; b++)
                    kare.Add(new DrawAction(new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(int.Parse(RectangleColor[b]))), (Rectangle)r.ConvertFromString(Rectangle[b])));
                for (int t = 0; t < CycleColor.Length; t++)
                    cember.Add(new DrawAction(new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(int.Parse(RectangleColor[t]))), (Rectangle)r.ConvertFromString(Rectangle[t])));
                Panel1.Invalidate();
            }